# PHPUnit constraints extension gives error "PHPUnit_Util_Type::export()" not found

Tags: php, phpunit, constraints

I want a mock object that can tell me if:

1. when one of its methods are called
2. that one of the arguments passed to that method
3. is an array
4. and has a particular key/value pair.

I want to use PHPUnit's constraints to achieve, this, so my test code would look like this:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('\Jodes\MyClass');
$mock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('myMethod')
        ->with(
                $this->logicalAnd(
                    $this->isType('array'),
                    $this->arrayHasPair('my_key', 'my_value'),
                )
            );
// ... code here that should call the mock method
```

In [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487296/phpunit-verifying-that-array-has-a-key-with-given-value), the guy ended up writing his own constraint.

I found [this library](https://github.com/etsy/phpunit-extensions) which seems to implement quite a few nifty things. So I installed it by adding this line in my `composer.json`'s require section:

```
"etsy/phpunit-extensions": "@stable"
```

But when I try using it, I get an error. I use it like so:

```
class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function arrayHasPair($key, $value){
        return new PHPUnit_Extensions_Constraint_ArrayHasKeyValuePair($key, $value);
    }
    public function testmyMethod(){
        // code as per my example above
    }
}
```

But that produces this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Type::export() in C:\MyProject\vendor\etsy\phpunit-extensions\PHPUnit\Extensions\Constraint\ArrayHasKeyValuePair.php on line 50

[This previous question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567219/phpunit-util-typeexport-in-version-4-0) explains what the problem is, but I'm not sure what I should do about it. Does this mean that the developers of that library have abandoned it? Is there an alternative to use? Or what options do I have for fixing it? I'm amazed such basic constraints still don't exist in PHPUnit. Obviously I could write my own constraints but surely that's unnecessary?

Comment: I've been using [Mockery](https://packagist.org/packages/mockery/mockery) and [Hamcrest](https://packagist.org/packages/hamcrest/hamcrest-php) for this kind of constraint. Works well for me.

Comment: Thanks, looks brilliant! Trying it out now.

Comment: @Simba, do you know how I can use mockery/hamcrest to test if an argument is an array that contains a key/value pair? Would I need to write a closure that looks for the pair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PHPUnit_Util_Type::export()` method was removed a while ago. The extension you want to use has to be updated to be compatible with current versions of PHPUnit.